# Nokia Lumia800 wifi with lock screen

Tags: windows-phone, wifi

Is it possible to use a background agent or a reminder to keep
the wifi alive?
Let's say i let a background agent open a connection to a server every minute or so.
The wifi will shutdown after two minutes but then you reconnect.

Is this possible? or am I totally wrong?

This is a big problem for all Windows Phone users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with a background agent.

> Periodic agents typically run every **30 minutes**. To optimize battery life, periodic agents may be run in alignment with other background processes and therefore the execution time may drift by up to 10 minutes.
>
> Resource-intensive agents typically run for **10 minutes**. There are
>   other constraints that may cause an agent to be terminated early

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=vs.92).aspx

And you can not turn on wifi without user intervention

Comment: But when the wifi is turned on and they run my program. Then they go to the background. I use pushnotifications. Then they go in lock and the wifi stops working. So if i bring back the wifi after 10 minutes then it should work?